# A ShouldSkipPage function inside CurPageChanged procedure

Tags: inno-setup

I want my setup to move to the next page from within a `CurPageChanged` procedure,

**Details-** I replace the `wpInstalling` with `ProgressPage` to make the installtion prograss more neat,
After `ProgressPage` finish I want to move to next page, so I entered `ShouldSkipPage` function,

but when I compile the setup I keep getting the "Identifier excepted " error message on the `function ShouldSkipPage(curPageId : Integer)` line.

```
procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
    var
      I: Integer;
begin
  case CurPageID of
    MOPage.ID:
    begin
      // this code executes for the first page, so let's setup the buttons however you want
      WizardForm.BackButton.Visible := False;
      WizardForm.NextButton.Caption := '&Agree and Install';
      WizardForm.CancelButton.Caption := '&Abort';
    end;
    SOPage.ID:
    begin
      // this code executes for the second page, so let's setup the buttons however you want
      SkipSOSwitch := 1;
      WizardForm.BackButton.Visible := False;
      WizardForm.NextButton.Caption := '&Agree and Install';
      WizardForm.CancelButton.Caption := '&Decline';
      WizardForm.CancelButton.OnClick := @SkipSOEvent;
    end;
    FSPage.ID:
    begin
      WizardForm.NextButton.Caption := SetupMessage(msgButtonFinish);
      WizardForm.NextButton.OnClick :=  @FinishButtonOnClick;
    end;
    IDPForm.Page.ID:
    begin
    // show the detail components
    idpShowDetails(True);
    // and hide the details button
    IDPForm.DetailsButton.Visible := False;
    end;
   wpInstalling: 
   begin
    ProgressPage.SetText('Starting installation...', 'Installing Wise Convert');
    ProgressPage.SetProgress(0, 0);
    WizardForm.ProgressGauge.Width := 600;
    ProgressPage.Show;
    try
    for I := 0 to 20 do begin
    ProgressPage.SetProgress(I, 20);
    Sleep(150);
    end;
    finally
    Sleep(3000);
    ProgressPage.Hide;
    function ShouldSkipPage(curPageId : Integer) : Boolean;
    begin
    Result := True
    end;
    end;
//  end else
//  WizardForm.NextButton.OnClick(WizardForm.NextButton);
    end;
    //StartTick := GetTickCount;
    end;        
  end;
```

Answer (score 2):

That error occurs because you are trying to declare your [`ShouldSkipPage`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=ShouldSkipPage) event method from inside another method. Your problem could be actually simplified to this piece of code:

```
[Code]
procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  function ShouldSkipPage(PageID: Integer): Boolean;
  begin
    Result := True;
  end;
end;
```

Such construction is not allowed. You cannot declare event methods inside another ones. They cannot be nested, in any way (though your declaration is not actually nested). The only allowed way to declare them is this:

```
[Code]
procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin

end;

function ShouldSkipPage(PageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  Result := True;
end;
```

So you have to move your [`ShouldSkipPage`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=ShouldSkipPage) event method declaration out of your [`CurPageChanged`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptevents.htm#CurPageChanged) event method. If you want your events cooperate somehow, you will have to use some globally declared variable(s).

Comment: 10x TLama, so how can I tell the setup to move to the next page within the `CurPageChanged`procedure?

Comment: That's what `WizardForm.NextButton.OnClick(WizardForm.NextButton);` would do. But since you've (probably, don't know the order of your pages) assigned a different method to the next button's `OnClick` event, you will need to store the original `OnClick` method and invoke that stored method.

Comment: But I cannot tell you that will work for you since I don't know the overall aim...

Comment: my aim is to replace the install page with costume ProgressPage (because of the known freeze issue on the install page) the problem is that the costume ProgressPage bar loops endlessly and not moving to the next page, and here I tried the `ShouldSkipPage` to move me to next page